# What will be returned from std::set.end() exactly in c++?

Tags: c++, stl

When you refers to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/end), you will find this:

> Returns an iterator to the element following the last element of the
>   container. This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it
>   results in undefined behavior.

Then I run the following code:

```
std::set<int> s {1, 2, 3};
cout << *s.end() << endl;
```

The out put is: **3**, why?

Comment: undefined behavior means anything can happen.  Including three.

Comment: Undefined behaviour that looks like it "works" is the most insidious kind.

Comment: with visualc++ i get the following error: "map/set iterator not dereferencable" :)

Comment: I got it, thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What will be returned from std::set.end() exactly in c++?

It returns:

> an iterator to the element following the last element of the container.

Note that:

> This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.

> The out put is: 3, why?

Because:

> attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.

so it can do anything your compiler feels like doing, and returning 3 is a kind of anything, that your compiler apparently felt like doing.

Comment: @cong I mean, you *did* have most of the information right in front of you already...